# Visual Studio Code - Adjust import quotation setting

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

When working in TypeScript in Visual Studio Code, the import suggestion on a type (triggered by space + period) will generate an import using double quotes.

Our TypeScript linter verifies that single quotes are used where possible.

As you can see below, the suggestion has double quotes ("@angular/...")
[image: Import suggestion with double quotes]

How can I adjust the setting of the import?

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode

Answer (score 214, accepted):

"typescript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single"

For more info see:

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_24#_preferences-for-auto-imports-and-generated-code

Comment: `"typescript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single"`

Comment: This doesn't seem to take effect for me. I still get double quotes from suggestions and snippets.

Comment: Same to me, changed on all possibles levels (user, workspace, project) and still have double quotes :(

Comment: I don't know what language you two are using but there are separate settings for javascript and typescript. I was wondering the same thing but I set the javascript code setting and not typescript.

Comment: Yep, if using javascript you will need `"javascript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single"`

Answer (score 57):

You can also configure the below line in your vscode user settings to adjust this setting.

```
"prettier.singleQuote": true
```

Comment: prettier is an extension, not everyone use it

Comment: Frustrating that people assume you have or want to use Prettier. Unless someone asks "how do I with Prettier" - I think it's best not to answer assuming they have it.

Comment: @TsarBomba You're right. This setting requires Prettier extension for adjusting the quotation.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode

Answer (score 19):

I fixed that using [Editor config](http://editorconfig.org/), open your **.editorconfig** file in your project root directory (if you don't have, create that file) and add this line after the **[*]**

```
[*]
...
quote_type = single
```

In the [wiki](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/wiki/EditorConfig-Properties) you can see the complete list of properties.

Comment: Upvoted. Restricts changes only to what project you're working on vs globally. Additional note: _restart VS Code_ to make the changes go into effect.

Comment: Just to comment, In VS Code you can set workspace settings that are specific to that project as well. This will allow you to use single/double quotes specifically on the import if you want to use the other type elsewhere within the files.  The .editorconfig change will be project wide.

Answer (score 17):

As of VS Code 1.21.1 you need to edit

> */usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/typescript-basics/snippets/typescript.json*

**In Windows**

> */Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/typescript-basics/snippets/typescript.json*.

**In Windows 10 (vscode version 1.30.* (user setup) later)**

> *C:\Users\<yourusername>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\typescript-basics\snippets\typescript.json

In the 'Import external module' section of that file make the body array property to be the value `"import { $0 } from '${1:module}';"` The section will then look like this:

```
"Import external module.": {
    "prefix": "import statement",
    "body": [
        "import { $0 } from '${1:module}';"
    ],
    "description": "Import external module."
},
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. Literally tried everything but only this fixed it.

Comment: Same here. Literally tried every other solution. This is the only one that solved my issue.

Answer (score 8):

An alternative which does support this configuration is [TypeScript Toolbox](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DSKWRK.vscode-generate-getter-setter).

It is configurable by setting `genGetSet.pathStringDelimiter`, which already has the single-quote import as default.

Comment: Thanks for this! Worth pointing out the `genGetSet.spacedImportLine` setting as well so new import lines look like `import { Router }....` instead of the default `import {Router}...`

Comment: Both the answer and the comment above are great information! Thanks you two!

Answer (score 8):

Go to "File > Preferences > Settings" and then add this under user settings:

```
"typescript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single",
"javascript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single"
```

Comment: Works for me, Thanks! BTW, you can add a link to the default settings which present these options: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings. `// Preferred quote style to use for quick fixes: 'single' quotes, 'double' quotes, or 'auto' infer quote type from existing imports. Requires using TypeScript 2.9 or newer in the workspace.`

Comment: There is no place to add code in File>preferences>Settings. A bunch of dialog boxes. Pess ctrl+shift+p and search for user settings and select the user settings json. And still it does not work

Answer (score 3):

As of TypeScript 2.5, the first import or export statement in the file will be scanned to determine if single or double quotes are used when using import suggestions.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/17750

Answer (score 3):

If You are using Pretier extension.
Just use the shortcut **ctrl+shift+p** and search for user settings.
Select user settings Json dropdown.
It will open the settings.json
And then add this 3 lines at the bottom

```
"javascript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single",
"typescript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single",
"prettier.singleQuote": true
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also configure the below line in your vscode user settings to allow single quote in string.

Go to Preferences > User Settings

```
"prettier.singleQuote": true
```

This will allow single quote in String. Otherwise, if you manually change all double quotes to single quotes it will revert back while saving. Also, add

```
"tslint.autoFixOnSave": true
```

to auto-fix while saving.

Answer (score 1):

This is already implemented (as mentioned in another reply)! But you are probably not on the latest version of TypeScript yet.

Solution is simple:

Click TypeScript version number (for example 2.3.4) between "TypeScript" and a little smiley face in the lower right corner. Then switch to Visual Studio Code built-in version (2.5.3 at this moment).

After this Visual Studio code will **infer import quote style by looking at the first import statement**. Note that a little popup label will still show double-quotes anyway.

[Bug report](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13270)

[Relevant pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/17750):

> This adds the ability to determine whether to use single or double quotes for new imports added via code fixes. When a new import is added, we scan the top-most statements of the source file for existing import or export declarations with module specifiers. We then use the quote style of the first one we find. If there are no existing imports in the file we fall back to using double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Above solutions did not work for me

So here is my work around, in you use vscode, `"tslint.autoFixOnSave"`: true in your `settings.json` will automatically fix these import quotations when you save the file.

Comment: Says `Unknown Configuration Setting`

Answer (score 0):

Open command pallete (Ctrl+Shift+P - on Windows), browse `Configure User Snippets`

[image]

Select `typescript.json (TypeScript)`

[image]

Paste this snippet to your list:

```
"Import external module.": {
    "prefix": "import statement",
    "body": [
        "import { $0 } from '${1:module}';"
    ],
    "description": "Import external module."
}
```

You are welcome:

[image]