# Is there a way to change from double quotes to single quotes in VS Code quick fix?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

When using VSCode with Angular, I write my import statement list this:

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
```

The VSCode Quick Fix adds them like this:

```
import { WelcomeComponent } from "app/home/welcome.component";
```

Is there a way to change the VS Code Quick Fix with a VS Code setting to use single instead of double quotes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check your `tslint.json` for the `quotemark` part.

If it's setted to use `doublequote` by

```
"quotemark": [
  true,
  "double"   < ------mention here
]
```

then there will be warning at your `typescript` file while using `singlequote`. And this will lead VS Code's quick-fix(show fix option for me) to change `singlequote` to `doublequote`.

So the solution should be change `double` to `single`.

```
"quotemark": [
  true,
  "single"   < ------change here
]
```

Comment: This is not accurate. This setting only changes the lint settings, it does not alter VS Code's behaviour.

Comment: @Spikeh you got any solution?

Comment: I posted this weeks before I found one. However, I've completely forgotten how I did it and there's no docs. See this discussion for some suggestions: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13270

Comment: See the accepted answer of this SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42952453/visual-studio-code-adjust-import-quotation-setting for the corresponding setting in VS Code

Answer (score 19):

If your project has a `.editorconfig` file, try adding the following line:

```
[*]
...
quote_type = single
```

I've found that the `.editorconfig` file seems to override any settings for vscode, prettier, tslint, etc. and it seems to default to something other than single quotes.

Deleting the file can work as well if you don't need it.

More info on [editorconfig](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/wiki/EditorConfig-Properties).

Comment: In case it saves someone else some time: this doesn't work yet (at least for me in June 2020 in VS Code) as `quote_type` is a [proposed idea](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/wiki/EditorConfig-Properties#ideas-for-domain-specific-properties) and not yet an official property. Here's the [feature proposal](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/issues/410).

Comment: I suppose I should add the caveat that I've only ever encountered the problem/solution with the .editorconfig file in an Angular application. It could be dependent on what extensions are installed...

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me while none of the other did.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the [Prettier Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) with the following settings (global/workspace).

```
"prettier.singleQuote": true
```

Answer (score 7):

This works nice and simply...

Open settings in VSCode, e.g. Command + ',' and then filter for
"typescript":

[image]

Look for "quote style" and change:

[image]

Comment: Nope, this option is gone. Why does VS Code team keep removing settings that weren't broken?

Comment: Just used this. Option exists and worked perfectly

Answer (score 4):

Press Ctrl + , for settings.

Then search for prettier. Find the setting Prettier: Single Quote

Set that to true.

You can set that in user settings or work space setting.

Answer (score 3):

open the VS Code `settings.json` after change typescript setting to

```
 "[typescript]": { "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features" }
```

[image]

Comment: You can use the command `CTRL + SHIFT + P` to open the command palette, then search for settings. You should see `Open Settings (JSON)`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this extension called "ECMAScript Quotes Transformer" that you can install by pressing :

```
Ctrl/Cmd + P
```

and type

```
ext install es-quotes
```

[ECMAScript Quotes Transformer on Visualstudio.com](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vilicvane.es-quotes)

Answer (score 0):

In **tslint.json**

**quotemark** should be set inside **rules**

```
{
    "defaultSeverity": "error",
    "extends": ["tslint:recommended"],
    "jsRules": {},
    "rules": {
      "quotemark": [true, "single", "avoid-escape", "avoid-template"],
      "no-console": false
    },
    "rulesDirectory": [],
    "compilerOptions": {
      "types": ["reflect-metadata", "jest"],
       "typeRoots": ["./types", "./node_modules/@types"]
     },
     "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts", "**/*.test.ts"],
     "include": ["./**/*.tsx", "./**/*.ts"]
  }
```