# How do I make VSCode JavaScript import snippet use single quotes?

Tags: javascript, formatting, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

The VSCode setting ["javascript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42952975/8407719) did not work for me and I'm still getting double quotes in my JavaScript snippets as shown in the picture:

[image: image showing snippet using double quotes]

Is there a way I can make VSCode use single quotes **without having to use any external extension like Prettier?**

Comment: The ` "javascript.preferences.quoteStyle"` setting controls quote style for auto imports and refactoring. The example you show is a snippet which is hardcoded to use double quotes. You can create your own snippet if you wish to use single quotes

Comment: @MattBierner I see. It would be great if VSCode gave us the ability to customize their inbuilt snippets to use single quotes instead of us having to create a new one.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you have a plugin that dictates the style of quotes. Have you tried changing the EditorConfig?
https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/wiki/EditorConfig-Properties

quote_type = "single"

But changing the preferences as you did would do the job. Going to try on my machine and edit this comment if I find out something.

You could also read about this PR to VSCode: 
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/17750

BTW Maybe your snippets plugin has hardcoded double quotes

Comment: The "import" snippet I am using is from VSCode's built-in JavaScript Language Basics extension as shown in the picture. It's not any external plugin using double quotes.

Comment: Also, adding "quote_type: single" in my settings.json does not work and shows that it's an unknown configuration.

Answer (score -1):

You’ll need to create a custom snippet. See: [Create your own snippets](https://Create%20your%20own%20snippets).

To “replace” the existing snippet, you’ll need to hide it from IntelliSense. See: [Can I remove snippets from IntelliSense?](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_can-i-remove-snippets-from-intellisense)